# How to set DeveloperTeam based on Scheme in Xcode

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

I have an Xcode workspace with a few schemes. One of my schemes is for an enterprise build and has a different Team ID. **I would like to automate changing the DeveloperTeam property based on the scheme**, but I can't figure out a way to do this. There doesn't seem to be anything in Build Settings to control this.

Any suggestions/solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a new target and change its setting to use a different provisioning profile/certificate pair. And then create a scheme for that target.

Or maybe I didn't understand your requirement?

Comment: That might work. Wish I didn't have to create a duplicate target for one setting change, but it may come to that

Comment: @tettoffensive You don't have to. You can create a xcconfig file and change settings there. Then create a new configuration from the xcconfig file and finally associate a scheme with it. This is how `Cocoapods` changes your settings. But it depends on your requirement.

Comment: @j-wang cool. I'll look into it. I'm using fastlane to build for CI. So I'll see if they have a nice way to do this